Finding the cumulative distribution of Y, when Y is a piecewise function with two different pdfs depending on another random variable X.
I am working on finding the CDF of Y. For the following problem, but I am not sure if what I am doing is fully correct. The problem is the following:
Suppose X ~ $N(0,1).$ Let Y = $X^{+},$ if $|X| \le C$ and Y = -X, if $|X| > C$. Find the distribution (e.g. CDF) of Y.
Since two cases define the function of the random variable Y. I broke the problem down into two cases. When the $|X| \le C$. We get P($Y\le y$) = P($X^{+} \le y$) = $F_{X}(X^{+}).$
For $|X|<C$, P($Y \le y$) = P($-X \le y$) = P($X \ge -y$) = 1-P($X < -y$) =1-$F_{X}(-y-\frac{1}{n})$.
This is what I have so far, but I would like to get to a more explicit form of the CDF of Y. As the following problem, asks me to compute the  COV(X,Y).

I assume the question is about the case where  $Y = -X$ if $|X| > C$, and  $Y = +X$ if $|X| \le C$.
Note that $N(0,1)$ has a distribution symmetric about $0$ so $F_X(x)=P(X \le x)=P(X\ge -x)$ and this is $\Phi(x)=1-\Phi(-x)$.

For $y<-C$, you have $P(Y \le y)=P(-X \le y) = P(X\ge -y) $ $= \Phi(y)$.

For $-C<y<C$, you have $P(Y \le y)$ $=P(-X \le -C) + P(-C \lt X \le y) $ $= \Phi(-C)+\big(\Phi(y)-\Phi(-C)\big)$ $=\Phi(y)$.

For $C<y$, you have $P(Y \le y)$ $=P(-X \le -C) + P(-C \lt X \le C) + P(C \le -X \le y)$ $= \Phi(-C)+\big(\Phi(C)-\Phi(-C)\big) +\big(\Phi(y)-\Phi(C)\big)$ $=\Phi(y)$.


So $F_Y(y)=P(Y \le y) = \Phi(y)$ and thus $Y \sim N(0,1)$ too.
The covariance question is interesting, though you have not attempted it yet.  For very large $C$ it will be almost $+1$ (the variance of each distribution) while for $C$ just above $0$ it will almost $-1$.  There is a value for $C$ for which it is $0$ despite $Y$ being determined by $X$, namely $1.538172\ldots$, which is the square root of the median of a chi-squared distribution  with $3$ degrees of freedom.

I don't think it is quite right, since $P(-C < Y < 0) = 0$

@LeanderTilstedKristensen You may be correct if $Y=X^+$ is meant to signify $Y=\max(0, X)$, but this is such a classic question when including the covariance part, that I suspect that it was intended to mean $Y=+X$, i.e. $Y=X$, and my answer does it that way.  I have put this as an initial thought in my answer.
